# Struct method returns different value every other run while testing

Tags: ios, swift

What could be the reason for this strange behaviour. I have the following six constants in a method that belongs to a `struct`.

```
    let crossSouthWest1 = getCrossProduct(x, y: y, from: .SouthWest)
    let crossSouthWest2 = getCrossProduct(x, y: y, from: .SouthWest)
    let crossSouthWest3 = getCrossProduct(x, y: y, from: .SouthWest)
    let crossSouthWest4 = getCrossProduct(x, y: y, from: .SouthWest)
    let crossSouthWest5 = getCrossProduct(x, y: y, from: .SouthWest)
    let crossSouthWest6 = getCrossProduct(x, y: y, from: .SouthWest)
```

And while creating unit tests for that `struct` I bumped into this strange behaviour where I get `nil` return values on valid input. So I placed a `breakpoint` and spammed copies of a single method call and this is what I got.

[image: bizarre]

Please note that the same code produces the desired results with the exact same input in a playground.

[image: playground]

Here's the method in question:

```
func getCrossProduct(x: Int, y: Int, from planarDirection: PlanarDirection) -> Float3? {
    let u = getAdjacentVertex(x, y: y, from: planarDirection.cardinalDirections.0)
    let v = getAdjacentVertex(x, y: y, from: planarDirection.cardinalDirections.1)

    if let vNotNil = v {
        if let uNotNil = u {
            let from = getVertex(x, y)
            let toU = uNotNil.subtract(from)
            let toV = vNotNil.subtract(from)

            return toU.crossProductWith(toV)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Here's code for the `getAdjacentVertex`.

```
func getAdjacentVertex(x: Int, y: Int, from direction: Direction) -> Float3? {
    let modifierX       = (direction == .West) ? 1 : 0
    let modifierWidth   = (direction == .East) ? -1 : 0
    let modifierY       = (direction == .North) ? 1 : 0
    let modifierHeight  = (direction == .South) ? -1 : 0

    if x >= modifierX &&
        x < width + modifierWidth &&
        y >= modifierY &&
        y < height + modifierHeight {
        return getVertex(x - modifierX - modifierWidth, y - modifierY - modifierHeight)
    }
    return nil
}
```

### Update

I've removed all variables from each one of those methods, but the result remains the same.

Comment: You are aware, I hope, that the debugger variable display is unreliable.

Comment: No, I wasn't aware of that. Still, in the unit test the method returns nil even though it should return a proper value.

Comment: The most likely explanation is there is some mutating global state elsewhere in your program not given in your snippet (i.e. in one of the other functions you're calling) that you don't realize is there (and that is not getting carried over into your playground test).  Even though this is a non-mutating method on a struct, that's not completely bulletproof, as if it accesses mutable global vars or uses classes they might be getting mutated.

Comment: You need to post your code for 'getAdjacentVertex'. Also you should learn how to add/use 'println' to debug

Comment: You might also want to consider factoring out the mapping from ordinal to cardinal direction enums into a separate function so that you don't need to use `var` to declare `u` and `v` (the more `var` you eliminate the better chance you have of not running into accidental mutation).

Comment: @MobileBen I've added the code for the other function. As for the other suggestions, the only global state is a `vertexArray` which is an instance of this struct created in the `setup` method of the test class.

Comment: Add diagnostic prints to figure out what causes a nil to be returned.  Ie, do some actual debugging.

Comment: Needs `getVertex` too.  Looks like `width` and `height` are externally defined, are they struct members?  And again, I'd suggest refactoring the switch to get the modifiers so you don't need to use `var` – all these assignments make it so easy to typo `modifierWidth` as `width` and suddenly you're mutating something accidentally.

Comment: @HotLicks you're just assuming I'm not using prints, without asking what have I used to ACTUALLY debug this. A bit condescending, no?

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity so the way I understand your suggestion, I should create a method that returns modifier depending on a direction argument?

Comment: If you were, you'd know where the algorithm was going awry.

Comment: In this case, you might be better off just doing `let newX = direction == .West ? x : x+1` or the like.  In case of `PlanarDirection` to `Direction` mapping, something like a read-only property on `PlanarDirection` such as `var cardinalDirections: (Direction,Direction) { switch self { case .NorthEast: return (.North,.East) etc... } }` – then you could do `let (vertDirection,horizDirection) = planarDirection.cardinalDirections`, then use those in your two calls to `getAdjacentVertex`